# kill the photostorage tag?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags

I think on this site, [photostorage](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photostorage) is implied to be just [storage](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storage). It's used on a few merged questions so I can't edit it out manually. Could a moderator please merge the tag? Thanks!

Comment: Done. Tags have been merged.

Comment: thanks @Joanne!